# how to print all sugession came in auto suggetions?

Tags: selenium

i Just started with selenium so i want to know how to handle below thing ...
when type some thing on google it gives us suggestions i want print them on console .
i have tried this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("cognizant i");

            List<WebElement> lst=driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            int ii = lst.size();

        System.out.println(lst.get(3).getText());
        System.out.println(lst);
        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){ 

            System.out.println("hi" + lst.get(i).getText());
        }
```

But not printing any thing on console. plz Guide me where i went wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Following code waits for the suggestions to appear after you have entered some value in `google` search bar and then prints them one by one in console:

```
     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Cognizant i");

    List <WebElement> allItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sbtc']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul//li/div[contains(@id,'sbse')]"));
    while(allItems.size() <1)
    {}

    System.out.println("Total no of elements :" + allItems.size() );

    for(int i=0; i< allItems.size() ;i++){
        value1= allItems.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(value1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually runs, and does output the suggestions - however you are grabbing all 'li' elements on the page which results in a large number of empty or irrelevant elements being present in your List lst.

You can see this if you open the Console in your browser on the google home page and search for li tags which is effectively what your code is doing.

Make your code more specific to the list items you want to collect - which reside inside a  tag with the role "listbox".

The following will output the suggestions to the console:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("cognizant i");

WebElement suggestionList = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[role ='listbox']"));
List<WebElement> suggestions = suggestionList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

for(WebElement suggestion : suggestions){
    System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
}
```